# Question about loops(closed paths) in $\mathbb{S}^{1}$

Tags: general-topology, circles, homotopy-theory, parametrization

Let

$$\alpha \left(s \right) =\left( \cos{2\pi s},\sin{2\pi s}\right)$$ and $$\beta \left(s \right) =\ \left( \alpha \land\left( \alpha \land \overline{\alpha}  \right)\right)\left( s \right)$$ with $s \in \left[0,1 \right]$ and $\overline{\alpha}=\alpha \left( 1-s \right)$  be two loops (closed paths) in $\mathbb{S}^1$.

With $\land$ defined as:

$$\left(\gamma_{1}\land\gamma_{2}\right)\left(s\right)=\begin{cases}
\gamma_{1}\left(2s\right) & s\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
\gamma_{2}\left(2s-1\right) & s\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]
\end{cases}$$

---

These are the things that I want to find:

1. An **explicit parametrization** of $\beta$.
2. An **homotopy lifting** of $\beta$, $\beta ':I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $\beta '\left( 0 \right)=1$.
3. **Homotopy** $F \left(s,t \right)$ between $\beta$ and $\alpha$ relative to the point $\left( 0,1\right)$, in other words, so that $F \left(0,t \right)=F \left(1,t \right)= \left(1,0 \right)$ $\forall t$.

Any ideas? I will edit this post with my advances so I with your help can develop an answer

Comment: Is your second expression missing an '$=$'-sign? Also, in what context did you find/get this problem? And what have you tried and where did you get stuck? As it stands you just seem to be asking for your homework to be done.

Comment: No, I'm asking for ideas so I can post my advances so I can do it, is not that I haven't tried anything is just that is a progressive exercise and I don't know how to start.

Comment: Ok. The first two expressions still don't make sense though.

Comment: The idea is that the path $\beta$ traces out $\alpha$ twice, then goes backward along $\alpha$ once. So you end up with something homotopic to $\alpha$. To find the parametrization of $\beta$, just unwind the definitions... it will be a piecewise-defined parametrization with a bunch of pieces, and will give you something to work with for the other parts. With what you wrote, you can only go as far as the abstract parametrization of $\alpha$ to write down the parametrization of $\beta$, since you did not give us $\alpha$ explicitly.

Comment: I made some mistakes typing it in latex, now is correct, sorry. @JaneDoé

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for the respective exercises:

1. Write out the definition.
2. A lifting to where?
3. The loop $\beta$ first traces the loop $\alpha$ twice, and then traces back $\alpha$ in reverse. To construct a homotopy, contract the second part to a point.  (By the second part, I mean the part tracing $\alpha$ once and then tracing $\alpha$ back in reverse). You can achieve this by a homotopy of the source spaces, i.e. a homotopy $[0,1]\ \longrightarrow\ [0,1]$. Here's a picture of this homotopy:
   [image]

Comment: Answering to the question of 2., is a lifting from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I can't find the homotopy can you give an extra hint please?

Comment: @JackTalion I've added a picture of the homotopy of the source spaces that induces the desired homotopy of loops.